# Managing a dual graphics card system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce, msi

I have a MSI GS43VR, that means I have both  Intel HD Graphics 530 and
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060. Lately, I started noticing that my battery is running low very quickly and the fan is working very loudly while I'm just browsing the internet. I think Ubuntu uses GTX1060 to render web pages :) How can I check which card is in use currently? And are there any drivers for my 1060 or will be I forced to use Windows? 
Right now I installed the `nvidia-375` package, while `nvidia-381` gives me

```
kernel BUG: soft lockup - CPU stuck for 23s!
```

Comment: What problem did you have with the open source driver ? For the closed source see - https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/ . As far as "will be I forced to use Windows?" no noe is forcing you to do anything. If your current graphics card does not work you can easily obtain an inexpensive graphics card and replace yours for the cost of a Windows license.

Comment: The open-source driver, at least the one preinstalled in Ubuntu gives me blank screen and again `kernel BUG: soft lockup - CPU stuck for 23s!`, that is why I installed a closed-source `nvidia-375`. Imho, buying a GTX1060 and then removing it for the sake of not using Windows is ridiculous.

Comment: The idea of purchasing hardware that is compatible with your OS is not ridiculous, it is how you buy hardware, period. You would not buy hardware knowing it was incompatible with windows and then make the same complaint with windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the recommended driver for gtx1060 and ubuntu 16.04 is nvidia-384

still cannot switch to intel, because I get a blank screen, but the nvidia driver works okay.